# Loading only third party trusted assemblies in an Application Server

Tags: security, architecture, digital-certificate, testcase

***Scenario***

I want to design a server which loads plug-in assemblies from third party vendors. The third party vendor needs to follow some contract while implementing plug-in assemblies. The third party plug-in assemblies needs to be copied to a specified deployment folder of the server. The server will dynamically load the plug-in assemblies.**The server needs to load only those assemblies which are from a trusted source**.

***Possible Solution***

As one of the solution, the server could rely on digital certificate technology. The server should load only those assemblies which are digitally signed with a trusted root certificate authority. I am planning to derive test cases from the following diagram:

[image]

The leaf node (highlighted in purple) denotes the possible test cases.

I need to get ideas/feedback on the following:

- Whether the above mechanism based on digital certificates is good enough for the above mentioned scenario?
- What are other alternatives in addition to digital certificate technology?
- Are there any test cases missing that have not been considered (based on the above diagram)?

Thanks.

Comment: You should check on invalidation mechanism - Root CA should contain link to a service which lists baned certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Just some random thoughts.

While not the only way to do this (off the top of my head you could for example use a HMAC with specific keys, or just a public key algorithm such as RSA or DSA on their own) it is probably the best way to achieve what you want to do with the minimum of effort.

Of course I would presume you would act as the CA in this scenario and any third-party could get a certificate signed from you? If not, and would just go for say a Verisign cert etc. you might want to consider checking the key usage and enhanced key usage fields of the certificate to ensure it is suitable for signing binaries (to stop someone for example using an SSL cert).

As pointed out in the above comment you want to check any certificate revocation lists, although that might be covered in signed versus unsigned. You probably also want a distinct test case between a file which is unsigned completely, a file which is signed but incorrectly (say public keys don't match) and one which is signed but invalidated, e.g. the signature is not timestamped by a trusted authority and the certificate has expired, or the CRL stuff.

Also are you excluding the possibility where the signing cert is the CA? It is a dumb thing to have but technically there is nothing wrong with doing so. You could even just skip the whole CA stuff and get a third party to generate their own self-signed cert and send that to the administrator of the server who would add it to the list of valid certificates for use. The only reason for the CA is they are supposed to check the details of the person who wants it, depending on how you plan to use this system than might not be necessary.

Comment: You might consider an OCSP for handling revocation, I've not used one directly but I think its a newer approach to solving the CRL problem.